# Как оптимально найти есть ли объект с неким свойством в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Как в массиве объектов найти объект с неким свойством (result1) , который в свою очередь является массивом объектов. И в этом массиве найти объект у которого свойство  равно "5", или 6 или 5 и 6.

вложенность такая:

нужно найти есть ли "5".есть ли "6". есть ли "6" и "5" оптимальным способом

```
const testarray = [
{
   result1: [
      {"test2": "5"}, 
      {"test3": "6"}, 
      {"test4": "89"}
     ],

  result2: [
      {"test2": "51"}, 
      {"test3": "61"}, 
      {"test4": "5"}
     ],
    ...

},
{
   result1: [
      {"test22": "51"}, 
      {"test33": "61"}, 
      {"test42": "89"}
     ],

}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Набросал вот такое решение под специфику вашего массива с объектами и вложенными массивами. Надеюсь, все ясно по коду. В результате три массива:

- `arrHasFive` - массив содержащий только `5`
- `arrHasSix` - массив содержащий только `6`
- `arrHasBoth` - массив содержащий `5` и `6`

```js
const testArray = [
  {
    result1: [
      {"test2": "5"}, 
      {"test3": "6"}, 
      {"test4": "89"},
    ],
    result2: [
      {"test2": "51"}, 
      {"test3": "61"}, 
      {"test4": "5"},
    ],
  },
  {
    result1: [
      {"test22": "51"}, 
      {"test33": "61"}, 
      {"test42": "89"},
    ],
  },
  {
    result1: [
      {"test22": "5"}, 
      {"test33": "61"}, 
      {"test42": "89"},
    ],
  },
  {
    result2: [
      {"test22": "5"}, 
      {"test33": "6"}, 
      {"test42": "89"},
    ],
    result1: [
      {"test22": "52"}, 
      {"test33": "6"}, 
      {"test42": "89"},
    ],
  },
  {
    result1: [
      {"test22": "5"}, 
      {"test33": "64"}, 
      {"test42": "8"},
    ],
  },
];

var arrHasFive = [];
var arrHasSix = [];
var arrHasBoth = [];

_.forIn(testArray, (valueOne, keyOne) => {
  _.forIn(valueOne, (valueTwo, keyTwo) => {
    if (keyTwo == 'result1') {      
      var hasFive, hasSix = false;
      
      _.forIn(valueTwo, (valueTree, keyTree) => {
        if (_.some(valueTree, (value, key) =>  value == '5')) {
          hasFive = true;
        }
      });
      
      _.forIn(valueTwo, (valueTree, keyTree) => {
        if (_.some(valueTree, (value, key) =>  value == '6')) {
          hasSix = true;
        }
      });
      
      if (hasFive && hasSix) {
        arrHasBoth.push(valueTwo);
      } else if (hasFive && !hasSix) {
        arrHasFive.push(valueTwo);
      } else if (!hasFive && hasSix) {
        arrHasSix.push(valueTwo);
      }
    }
  });
});

console.log('`result1` objects has both values:', arrHasBoth);
console.log('`result1` objects has five value:', arrHasFive);
console.log('`result1` objects has six value:', arrHasSix);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Основные методы для проверки:

- [`_.forIn`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forIn) - итерация по каждому свойству объекта, при этом итератор вызывается с тремя аргументами: значение, ключ, объект `(value, key, object)`
- [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#some) - проверить, является ли предикат правдивым для любого элемента коллекции